# replace character in complex pattern

Tags: regex, linux, perl, awk, sed

I have data in file like:

```
1436387515496;Si gnal;strength;- 120;-160;-120 ;-1;-1;1;0.05. 789123;45.2285962  1436387523254;Si gnal;strength;- 120;-160;-120 ;-1;-1;1;10762 .05.7893792;45.2285062 1436387533164;Signal;stren gth;-120;-160 ;-120;-1;-1;0 ;10902.05.789335 ;45.228513143638 7536029;Signal;s trength;-120;- 160;-120;-1;- 1;1;3296.05.789 335;45.228513 1436387543135;Si gnal;
```

I want to add a new line (\r\n) every 13 characters before ";Si", any idea ?

PS: I don't know if we can use "sed" because all the file is in one line.

PS2: The 13 characters before ";Si" are always numbers.

Thanks

Comment: Please show your expected output.

Comment: What language are you using?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: When you say *every 13  characters*, do you also mean between `stre` and `ngth`, and between `-1` and `60` etc.?

Answer (score 2):

With sed:

```
sed -i 's/.\{13\};Si/\r\n&/g' filename
```

The trick here is the `&` in the replacement clause, which is replaced with the matched string (those 13 characters and the `;Si`).

The input in the question looks as though spaces should be removed prior to this step (the output I get without that step doesn't appear to make a lot of sense). If this is not just an artifact of copy/pasting, you can do it in one go with

```
sed -i 's/ //g; s/.\{13\};Si/\r\n&/g' filename
```

Comment: `^1` as I think you may have actually guessed the requirements correctly!

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pi -e 's,(?=.{13};Si),\r\n,g' filename
```

Meaning 'replace the existence of any 13 characters, followed by `;Si` with `\r\n`'. Worry not, for we do not replace the actual characters.

Answer (score 1):

Inserts `\r\n` between 13 numbers and `;Si`

```
$str =~ s|\b[0-9]{13}\K (?=;Si)|\r\n|xg;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '1436387515496;Si gnal;strength;- 120;-160;-120 ;-1;-1;1;0.05. 789123;45.2285962  1436387523254;Si gnal;strength;- 120;-160;-120 ;-1;-1;1;10762 .05.7893792;45.2285062 1436387533164;Signal;stren gth;-120;-160 ;-120;-1;-1;0 ;10902.05.789335 ;45.228513143638 7536029;Signal;s trength;-120;- 160;-120;-1;- 1;1;3296.05.789 335;45.228513 1436387543135;Si gnal;' |
sed -r 's/(.{13})(;Si)/\1\n\2/g'
1436387515496
;Si gnal;strength;- 120;-160;-120 ;-1;-1;1;0.05. 789123;45.2285962  1436387523254
;Si gnal;strength;- 120;-160;-120 ;-1;-1;1;10762 .05.7893792;45.2285062 1436387533164
;Signal;stren gth;-120;-160 ;-120;-1;-1;0 ;10902.05.789335 ;45.228513143638 7536029
;Signal;s trength;-120;- 160;-120;-1;- 1;1;3296.05.789 335;45.228513 1436387543135
;Si gnal;
```

Change `\n` to `\r\n` if you like. The above uses GNU awk for `\n` to represent newline and `-r` to enable extended regexps, with some seds (OSX?) you need `-E` instead or just escape the braces.

Note that with the given input all you actually need is:

```
sed 's/;Si/\n&/g'
```

or portably across all seds:

```
sed 's/;Si/\
&/g'
```